# Derivative of imaginary part of complex function $f(z)$ w.r.t $z$ and $\bar{z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, chain-rule

Let $\text{Im}(f(a))$ be denoted by $v(a)$, $v(a)=\frac{f(a)-\bar{f}(a)}{2i}$.

I want to find $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{a}}$.

Since, if I am correct, $\bar{f(a)}$ denotes the complex conjugate of the function $f(a)$, and not the complex conjugate as well as substituting $\bar{a}$ for $a$, I can not see a way to use e.g the chain rule and find a  more explicit expression for the $\bar{f(a)}$ term?

Thanks